# Sql date variable delphi

Tags: sql, delphi-2010

Im having trouble with my sql :

```
sSQL:= 'select * from tbldebit where transaction date like " '+ tdate+ ' " ' ;
```

Delphi 2010 keeps giving me missing operator error.
(TDate captures value from date time picker)

Look foward to your response

Regards

Comment: Is this Ruby or Delphi? You have "ruby" in your tags where you probably should have "delphi"...

Comment: `LIKE` is not valid for anything but strings. Use `=`, `>=`, `<=`, or `BETWEEN` for all other data types.

Comment: TDate is a type. I hope you don't have a variable named TDate. Also, you are going to be subject to SQL injection.

Comment: Apologies for the tag im new to this

Answer (score 0):

I have always used:

```
function DateTimeToSQLDate(const ADate: TDateTime): string;
var
  MyYear, MyMonth, MyDay, MyHour, MyMinute, MySecond, MyMSecond: Word;
begin
  DecodeDateTime(ADate, MyYear, MyMonth, MyDay, MyHour, MyMinute, MySecond, MyMSecond);
  Result := Format('#%d %s %d#', [MyDay, FormatSettings.LongMonthNames[MyMonth], MyYear]);
end;
```

You would use this...

```
sSQL:= 'select * from tbldebit where [transaction date] = ' + DateTimeToSQLDate(TDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct code =
sSQL: ='Select * from tbldebit where [Transaction date] like " '+ datepicked+ ' " ' ;

The field name had to be in square brackets since their is a space in the name. I tested it and 'like' works.

Regards

Answer (score -3):

Use wildcards like below:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM tbldebit WHERE date LIKE '%" + tdate+ "%'";
```

Comment: I tried that but it still gives missing operator error

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: Nobody here knows what TDate is in your code. We don't know your error because you paraphrased it. Why don't you do some debugging. Inspect the exact SQL query. I understand that you are a novice, that's fine. You should set yourself the goal of learning how to debug. That's the best way for you to advance.

Comment: Im doing a search using sql. The user chooses a date from a datetimepicker and then the sql displays the records that include that date. The variable datepicked(tdate) is assigned the value of the datetimepicker.

Comment: If you want record of any particular date, then why are you using Like in SQL command?